# jQuery Ajax post to WCF getting bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, rest, post

I am attempting to create an auto-complete box... and I can retrieve appropriate JSON using Fiddler, but when implemented in code, I get a connection error.
Code:

```
<htm>
<Head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt_search" name="search">
<span id="suggest"></span>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#txt_search").keyup(function() 
    {

        var search; 
        search = $("#txt_search").val(); 

        if (search.length > 2) 
            { 

                // Trigger AJAX request 

                $.ajax( 
                { 
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "*****",
                    data: { "FirstPartOfName":"Med " },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(message)  { 
                        if (message.length > 0) 
                            { 
                            alert('It got data back....');
                            message = "Do you mean: " + message; 
                            $("#suggest").append(message);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            alert('Nothing came back....');
                            }
                        }
                }       );
            } 
            else { 
                // Empty suggestion list 
                $("#suggest").empty();
                } 
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot provide the URL, but I can connect using Fiddler to test it. I'm thinking it could be a problem with WCF, but how then can I test correctly with Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your primary problem here, but by setting the `contentType` to `application/json`, you're telling WCF that you're sending it parameters in JSON serialized format, but when you pass a native object to jQuery like that, it's going to URL encode those parameters instead. In other words, you're sending `?FirstPartOfName=Med` instead of `{"FirstPartOfName":"Med"}`. More about that here: http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

In this simple case, you can fix that by explicitly sending a JSON string instead:

```
data: '{"FirstPartOfName":"Med"}'
```

It looks similar, but is completely different over the wire.

Building the JSON string by hand is workable enough in the simplest case, but gets to be cumbersome. You can also [use JSON.stringify to automatically build the string from objects](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I was indeed making that error, however the problem remains. I still receive a bad request 400 error.

Comment: @user1120064: Can you show some of your WCF code/config? Do you have HttpPost enabled? Is the method decorated with a WebInvoke attribute that allows POST requests?

Comment: That was actually written by an individual who is no longer available, and I had just assumed it was done correctly. I will ask my admin if I can have access to it.

Comment: Can my WCF code be off that much, if I can get appropriate responses in Fiddler?

Comment: @user1120064: Are you crafting identical requests in Fiddler? For example, if you're testing a GET in Fiddler, that doesn't necessarily mean that your jQuery POST will work the same way. Ditto for the Content-Type, which does not default to `application/json`.

Comment: Here is what I was putting into Fiddler:    ||||| User-Agent: Fiddler
    Host: ****.com
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 26 |||||  That is all the headers, with this as the body: {"FirstPartOfName":"Med "}